# preg_replace doesn't work for my css strings

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a problem with `preg_replace`, I'm trying to replace in css-file strings, which have

```
   #id-name.class-name
```

structure with

```
   #id-name .class-name
```

(got space-character inside).

Here is my code:

```
 function getFileContent($file)
{
    $path = $this->_directory."/".$file;

    if(file_exists($path))
        return file_get_contents($path);
}

    function replaceCSS($fileCSS){

    $css_contents = $this->getFileContent($fileCSS);
    //$pattern_one = '/\#([a-zA-Z0-9\-]*)\./g';
    $css_contents = preg_replace('/#([a-zA-Z0-9\-]*)\./g','#\\1 .',$css_contents);
    echo $css_contents;
}
```

The result is `NULL`, if I get it right (it just displays nothing).
Regular pattern is right (checked it twice).
What is wrong with my syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `/g` modifier is not valid in PHP:

```
PHP Warning:  preg_replace(): Unknown modifier 'g' in ...
```

Remove it and will work...

Your modified line would be:

```
    $css_contents = preg_replace('/#([a-zA-Z0-9\-]*)\./','#\\1 .',$css_contents);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern:

> "@(#[^ ]+)(.[^ {]+)@ig"

and this substitution

```
"$1 $2"
```

I'm using [regex101](http://regex101.com/) to check my regexps

Answer (score 0):

In php it is better to use `$1` for a group reference. Also, I would change the first `*` in your regex to a `+` to make sure there are characters after the `#`.

```
$css_contents = preg_replace('/#([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)\./','#$1 .',$css_contents);
```